# push the current element into my array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, radio-button

I'm trying to push the current selected radio button into my array 'pen'. The entire collection is getting pushed. The current selections should be the shape, size, metal. I want to be able to concatenate them into an image url but I keep getting the entire array. How do I just get the current input values?

```
<h2>Pick a shape</h2>
<label>circle</label>
<input type="radio" name="shapes" value="circle" checked>
<input type="radio" name="shapes" value="square">
<label>square</label>
<input type="radio" name="shapes" value="heart">
<label>heart</label>
<br><br>

<hr>

<h2>Pick a metal</h2>
<input type="radio" name="metals" value="silver" checked>silver
<input type="radio" name="metals" value="bronze">bronze
<br><br>

<hr>

<h2>Pick a size</h2>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="sm">sm
<input type="radio" name="size" value="md" checked>md
<input type="radio" name="size" value="lg">lg

$('input:radio').change(function () {
  var c = document.getElementById("controls"); 
  var els = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var pen = new Array();
  //console.log(els);

  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {    
    if (els[i].type == "radio" && els[i].checked == true) { 
      pen.push(els); // Should I add 'this'
      console.log(pen);
    }
    console.log(pen[0] + "-" + pen[1] + "-" + pen[2] + ".png");
  }
});
```

Comment: I made an addition to my code 
        ...   
        if (els[i].type == "radio" && els[i].checked == true) { 
          pen.push(els[i].value);
        }
      var imageURL = "images/" + pen[0] + "-" + pen[1] + "-" + pen[2] + ".png";
      console.log(imageURL);
    }

The user clicks any one of the radio buttons and ultimately I get my image url as the third line in the console. But before I get that it prints out two other lines:

images/circle-undefined-undefined.png
images/circle-silver-undefined.png
images/circle-silver-md.png

I’m not sure I understand why that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the index `pen.push(els[i]);` ex:

```
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {    
  if (els[i].type == "radio" && els[i].checked == true) { 
    pen.push(els[i]); // Should I add 'this'
    console.log(pen);
  }
}

console.log(pen[0] + "-" + pen[1] + "-" + pen[2] + ".png");
```

Comment: I got it! I was printing out my image url inside of the loop. I moved it outside of the loop and I'm getting what I expected! images/square-silver-md.png

Problem solved! :)

Comment: I edited this answer to match your update. glad you fixed it.